# closing the browser after clicking the modal button using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a modal window containing the 'close' button, I need to close the browser once i click on the close button. how do i achieve using angular js.

I tried using **$window** service but no luck.

```
<div class="modal" id="alertModal" data-keyboard="true" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog text-left" style="width:40%">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h3>{{title}}</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="alert-danger" style="padding:10px; font-size:13px"><span ng-bind-html="content"></span></div> 
              </div>
                     <div class="modal-footer">
                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="closeBrowser();">Close</button>
                     </div>
              </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

### controller

```
$scope.closeBrowser = function(){
  $window.close();
}
```

Comment: It should work but you should inject $window in your controller ( dependency injection)

Comment: injected the $window service but same issue

Comment: try to use ng-click not onClick

Comment: by mistake i typed onclick instead ng-click

Comment: This method is only allowed to be called for windows that were opened by a script using the window.open() method. If the window was not opened by a script, the following error appears in the JavaScript Console: Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script.   check this link :https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
function closeWindow() {
    window.open('','_parent','');
    window.close();
}
```

Comment: i tried but i am getting the error saying: Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.

Comment: On wich browser? try this one please:   function closeWindow() {
    window.open('','_self','');
    window.close();
}

Comment: thanks..it is perfectly working  for chrome. but not working for firefox. Is there any solution for firefox?

Comment: check this link: http://www.yournewdesigner.com/css-experiments/javascript-window-close-firefox.html

Comment: I tried that one also. It may be because of version of firefox. I am using firefox 40.0.3.

Comment: hi, i tried in angular 15, but this is working :(